# What is the font of this invitation?

Tags: font-identification

This is the font that I want to identify, sorry for the poor image quality.

[image]

Comment: Hi Anna, welcome to GDSE.  We have some [requirements for font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions). It would be great if you review these, and edit your question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @Billy Kerr, I think in this case is nearly impossible to find a match with this image quality. Fight o'clock???? :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Opal](https://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Opal.font) from urbanfont.com (free font).

[image: OPAL 01]

[image: OPAL 02]

[image: OPAL 03]

---

[Dessau](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/fontsite/dessau?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=dessau) from fontspring.com (to buy).

[image]

Comment: or it could just be another Bauhaus... hard to know for sure with such low quality image.